# Symfony: How to enable validation errors from a subform to show up in the parent form?

Tags: validation, symfony

I have a form for `Namespace\Entity\MainEntity` which include a subform like this:

```
->add('property1',  TextType::class, array(
    'required'   => false,
    'label'      => 'This is the form label',
    'data_class' => 'Namespace\Entity\SubFormEntity', 
    'attr'       => array(
        'class' => 'form-control'
    )
))
->add('property2', SubFormType::class)
```

The `SubFormType` itself has a text field as shown below:

```
->add('subproperty1', TextType::class, array(
     'label' => false,
     'attr' => array(
         'class' => 'form-control'
     )
))
```

If I submit the form, `property1` gets validated correctly but validation for `property2` is not triggered and the form gets submitted even though the value for `subform_field` is incorrect.

I have tried ...

```
 Namespace\Entity\SubFormEntity:
    properties:
        property2:
            - Type:
                type: numeric
```

... and ...

```
Namespace\Entity\MainEntity:
    properties:
       property2.subproperty1:
           - Type:
               type: numeric
```

How can I enable validation for the `subproperty1` field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable `error_bubbling` ([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#error-bubbling)) to have your sub-form's errors show up in the parent form.

Use the following validation mapping for `SubFormEntity`:

```
Namespace\Entity\SubFormEntity:
    properties:
        subproperty1:
            - Type:
                type: numeric
```

Add the [`Valid`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html) constraint to your `MainEntity`'s validation mapping:

```
 Namespace\Entity\MainEntity:
     properties:
         property2:
             - Valid
```

Add the `error_bubbling` option to your `SubFormType`:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        // ...
        'error_bubbling' => true
    ));
}
```

... or add the option dynamically when including your `SubFormType` in your `ParentFormType` like this:

```
->add('property2', SubFormType::class, array(
    'error_bubbling' => true
))
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer !